# Spring MVC redirection without using annotations

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, controller, spring-webflow

I am not expert in Spring MVC and I'm have some dificulties to achieve the intented.

Basically, I need a Controller that will redirect to a web flow.

I know how to achieve this with the use of @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations. However, I cannot use spring-context as I'm restricted to version 2.5 (these annotations are present in 2.5 but application won't build with Java 8)

```
<bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/first/*">myMvcController</prop>
            <prop key="/toflow/*">myFlowController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="myMvcController" class="mypackage.controller.myController"/>

<bean id="myFlowController" class="org.springframework.webflow.executor.mvc.FlowController">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
    <property name="defaultFlowId" value="application-flow"/>
</bean>
```

And my controller looks something like:

```
public class myController extends Controller {
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    return new ModelAndView(forward:/toflow/variable)
```

Not sure if the forward is correct or if I should provide the url different, but the main problem is that the controller tries to resolve that as a view that doesn't exist. I just want to call /toflow/xxxx which I assume will be handle by my previous mapping and call my webflow.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `return new ModelAndView("redirect:/toflow/variable");`